# Open file manager as different user

Tags: permissions, user-management, display-manager, mir

can I open a file manager as a different user? (non-root)

When I try it, I get:

```
No protocol specified
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: Keine Berechtigung
Unable to init server: Verbindung ist gescheitert: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt
Could not parse arguments: Anzeige kann nicht geöffnet werden:`
```

(sorry for the german/english mix / that's how it's printed out - i can translate it, if necessary, but I think the problem is quite clear)

When I strace the start, it says that there is no permission to some socket files:

```
# cat strace | grep "/run/user/1000"
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/run/user/1000/wayland-0"}, 27) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/run/user/1000/mir_socket"}, 110) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path=@"/run/user/1000/broadway1.socket"}, 34) = -1 ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

None of these files even exist.

If I make that directory itself accessible for the other user with setfacl or chmod, it doesn't work either. The error message is the same and strace says this time: No such file or directory.

One may ask, why I want to do this, but it's quite a long story ... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open Nautilus as a different user follow these steps:

- Press `Alt + F2`
- Type in `gksu` and press enter.
- Choose the user and type in `nautilus` in the command box.
- Hit enter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It didn't work - however with gksu I managed to get it working: When I type 
    "gksu -u user nautilus & disown"
as root it works as I wanted!

Comment: You need to enter the user's password in the password box that follows.

Comment: This was great solution at the time of posting. +1. However, for those arriving here after 2023, or post Ubuntu 18.04, `gksu` has been removed unfortunately from Ubuntu.